# "Invalid input detected at '^' marker" error encountered. How to resolve?

Tags: networking, router, ip, cisco-router, cisco-packet-tracer

When attempting to configure a static route on a router in Packet Tracer, I run into an error where the g0/1 interface part of the code isn't accepted. What should I check first, or do to resolve this error message I keep getting? I have been following a tutorial, and doing exactly as the educator does- and this command worked for him, but not for me. This probably means it has something to do with the way Packet Tracer is set up, on my end?

[image]

Comment: Can you run “show interfaces vlan #” on the appropriate vlan? The CISCO documentation on creating a default route does not match what your doing

Comment: @Ramhound the command "show interfaces vlan#" gave the invalid input error, so I ran the command "show interfaces" on the Router CLI, and it said that "Vlan1 is administratively down". Running the "show vlan" command shows that the router is on Vlan 1. Should I try to change the status of Vlan1?

Comment: You did replace the # with an actual number of the vlan right? It seems you have more research into the configuration of the router and familiarization of the CISCO CLI

Answer (score 0):

You've tried `g0/0` - the zeroth interface in module 0 - which might not actually exist as port indices usually start with 1. Try `g0/1` instead.

If that doesn't work either make sure that the switch does have gigabit interfaces. You can display a list of interfaces by running `show interfaces`.

Also, `ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 g0/1` means *to reach 192.168.1.0/24 just talk out of g0/1*. You might need to configure a gateway instead of an interface, depending on your network.

Comment: Is that true? I'm only familiar with _old_ IOS, but the indices were zero-based as far as I remember. I have a Serial0/0, Serial1/0, and FastEthernet0/0 here.

Comment: Just check your router. We don't know which one you've picked.

Comment: @Zac67 I tried g0/1, it gave me the same error. Displaying the interfaces shows that the g0/0 interface is up and connected. I will research how to configure a gateway, thanks.

Comment: Just substitute the gateway IP address for where you tried to insert the interface name, e.g. `ip route 1921.68.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1`. You can also hit `?` after entering the network mask to show what input is expected.